# How to decrypt a secret message inside a text with given encryption key

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key

I have a text that is part of a roman. there is a secret message inside this text and I have a given encryption key as below:

Encryption key: 6132342135343721393631633233346221233132

I found the secret message inside the roman as below:

"2zujpggdxdtcergbifcw"

first question is, what kind of key can be this key?
and second, how it is possible to find this message and decrypt it?

Comment: What do you mean by "part of a roman"? Do you have *any* information about what kind of encryption has been used? Your description is extremely vague.

Comment: the roman is in link bellow. this is actually plain text.
http://shakespeare.mit.edu/hamlet/hamlet.1.3.html.

I found the message inside this roman and it is as bellow:
"2zujpjjdxdtce".

now I have to understand what is the message with given encryption key

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the roman" - it seems you're treating "roman" as a noun, but I don't know what you mean by it. That's just a bit of Hamlet - what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: In ASCII, you have : `a24!547!961c234b!#12` as key.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about decryption of text - without any reference to programming.

Comment: the program shod be written as java code. but first I have to know what kind of key is that. RSA, DES,...

Comment: how did you get a24!547!961c234b!#12 this key?

Comment: @JonSkeet Perhaps Niima means "novel". In many languages, a word similar to "roman" means "novel" while "novel" means "short story".

Comment: @ntoskrnl: Possibly. That's why I've been asking for clarification :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about decryption of text - without any reference to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to analyze the input string and the key.

The length of the string is 20 and the length of the key is 40, maybe you can rewrite them to obtain the same length.

Analyzing the key, you can recognize it as hex values of ASCII characters:

```
key = ['0x61', '0x32', '0x34', '0x21', '0x35', '0x34', '0x37', '0x21', '0x39', '0x36', '0x31', '0x63', '0x32', '0x33', '0x34', '0x62', '0x21', '0x23', '0x31', '0x32']
```

The input string "2zujpggdxdtcergbifcw" can be written in hex ASCII:

```
msg = ['0x32', '0x7a', '0x75', '0x6a', '0x70', '0x67', '0x67', '0x64', '0x78', '0x64', '0x74', '0x63', '0x65', '0x72', '0x67', '0x62', '0x69', '0x66', '0x63', '0x77']
```

Now the input string and the key have the same length, you can try to apply some bitwise operations to decrypt the message.

Trying with the XOR operator, for every element in the list:

```
secret[i] = msg[i] XOR key[i]
```

and the result is: "SHAKESPEAREWASHERE", this is a good result but is not very readable.

Since the ASCII is case sensitive, you can try to uppercase the 
input string "2ZUJPGGDXDTCERGBIFCW" and the result will be: "Shakespeare was here".

There is the code to decrypt the message in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

msg = '2ZUJPGGDXDTCERGBIFCW'
key = '6132342135343721393631633233346221233132'

# Creating a list of integers parsing the key string as hex values
key_parts = list(map(lambda x: (int(x,16)), map(''.join, zip(*[iter(key)]*2))))
# Creating a list of integers values of the msg string treated as ascii
msg_parts = list(map(ord, list(msg)))

# Applying the bitwise XOR and convert to char every result
secret_msg = ''.join(map(lambda x: chr(x[0] ^ x[1]), zip(msg_parts, key_parts)))

print(secret_msg) # Prints 'Shakespeare was here'
```

Comment: `map()` is obsoleted by generator expressions because they're more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not a Known encryption method like `RSA` or `MD5` or ...
You Need to find a pattern between your secret key and encryption key. This is called [Steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)

Comment: This is not what steganography is about. While you can encrypt a message for further security before hiding it with steganography, the purpose of steganography is to deny the knowledge that any secret is hidden in the first place. The asker already knows there is a secret message and has an encryption key. Blind steganalysis is the study of detecting a hidden message (possibly) exists when you don't know the embedding steganography algorithm. It is done using statistics and searching for modification patterns in the cover medium, but again, this is not what the asker is looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code of java version :

```
    String Encryption_key = "6132342135343721393631633233346221233132";
    List<Integer> Encryption_key_int = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Encryption_key.length(); i+=2) {
        String substr = Encryption_key.substring(i, i+2);
        Encryption_key_int.add(Integer.parseInt(substr, 16));
    }
    System.out.println(Encryption_key_int);

    String msg = "2ZUJPGGDXDTCERGBIFCW";
    List<Integer> msg_hex_int = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
        int ascii = (int) msg.charAt(i);
        msg_hex_int.add(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toHexString(ascii), 16));
    }
    System.out.println(msg_hex_int);

    String result = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < msg_hex_int.size(); i++) {
        char XOR_int = (char)(msg_hex_int.get(i) ^ Encryption_key_int.get(i));
        result += XOR_int;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

The output is :

[97, 50, 52, 33, 53, 52, 55, 33, 57, 54, 49, 99, 50, 51, 52, 98, 33, 35, 49, 50]

[50, 90, 85, 74, 80, 71, 71, 68, 88, 68, 84, 67, 69, 82, 71, 66, 73, 70, 67, 87]

Shakespeare was here

Comment: @NimaSoroush Thank you ! I got inspiration from the python version above ;)